# figuring out bug with django cookies: not working on server

Tags: django

I have a site that relies on checking if a cookie exists for `service_id` and if it does checks if you can upload files for service... this works nicely offline but on pushing changes to server it created a bug where even though the cookie can be seen (on the dev console)

[image]

and I assign the cookie to a context variable which ends up saying `None` even though I can see the cookie from the dev console.

```
class PictureCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Picture
    fields = "__all__"
    template_name = 'accounts/upload-file.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        context = super(PictureCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['service_id'] = self.request.COOKIES.get('service_id', None)

        return context
```

on the template

```
{% if service_id %}
    #display form
{% else %}
    Sorry it seems you're missing some vital data needed before ...
{% endif %}
```

any ideas?

here's a screen record (local & live): https://youtu.be/aud59Avp1aI

Comment: How are you setting the cookie?

Comment: And are you using secure cookies in production?

Comment: setting it from the view using response.set_cookie('service_id, <service_id>)

Comment: secure cookies?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/security/ If you have the setting forcing HTTPS, then you won't get the data back.

Comment: @cwallenpoole I don't have ssl on the site (there's a screen record in the edits)

Comment: That's the problem. If you have the setting to require HTTPS for cookies and you're not using HTTPS, then you won't see them

Comment: so is this nginx or gunicorn that configured this way?

Comment: resolved as suggested by getting ssl